# The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

## Environment

- Laravel Version : **4.2.17**
- PHP Version : **5.6.1**
- MAC OS X : **10.11**
- MAMP : **3.5**

---

## Description

The project loading fine on home page.

Anything else, but that I got this.

> The requested URL /login was not found on this server.

---

## Attempt

**check routes**

I have that routes declared in my `routes.php` file

```
Route::get('login',array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@showLogin'));
```

---

**apache settings**

MAMP > Apache Settings

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All <--- I've changed from 'None' -> 'All'
</Directory>
```

*Restart my MAMP, and same error occur*

---

## Question

Why do my server kept throwing me that error ?

What should I check ? Apache Settings of my MAMP ? or my PHP ? or my Laravel ?

Comment: A very bald question: is the virtualhost configured properly? (Can you reach localhost:8888 and do you see the home view there?)

Comment: The route is there, I'm not sure why it complain that it couldn't find it.

Comment: I usually never have adjust any of my vhost locally. But what do you have in mind ?

Answer (score 2):

After stuck on this more than a day, I've learned that I don't have `.htaccess` in my `public\` folder of my laravel project.

I created a `public\.htaccess` with this content in there

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

- Reboot my MAMP
- All of that nonsense is no-longer happening.
- Hope this answer help someone like me